# meaning of the notation $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$

Tags: general-topology, notation

I have been self studying Topology from Wayne patty and I don't know meaning of this notation which came up in the theorem  2.50 on Page 92.

> Statement of the theoerm: Let $\bar{d}$ be th estandard bounded metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and define D(x,y)=$ lub [\bar {d}( x_i ,y_i) /i ] $for all x,y $\in \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ .

What is meaning of the notation $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ ?

Comment: I expect it is in this context the set of infinite-length real sequences.  See for instance [omega language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_language) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $$X^{\omega}=X\times X \times \cdots $$
is an infinite countable product of $X$, it's to say the set of all countable sequences over $X$.